# Actualizar patron de texto en toda la base de datos

Tags: mysql

tengo el siguiente escenario:
tengo mysql server  y definidas múltiples base de datos y tablas.
el algunos campos de estas tablas tengo texto que incluye el nombre de documentos
ejemplo 1:

```
DocRel
CCTR0000007
```

ejemplo 2:

```
Memo
el documento CCTR0000007 fue cancelado
```

estoy tratando de  hacer lo siguiente:
existe alguna manera de **buscar y Actualizar en todos los lugares** el texto con las siguientes clausulas de busqueda:

```
tamaño de string definido: ejemplo 'CCTR0000007' 11 caracteres
pattern de string definido: ejemplo 'CCTR0000007' todos los que comiencen con CCTR
```

y que actualice el documento incrementando los ceros '0' ejemplo:

```
CCTR0000007
a:
CCTR00000000000007
```

**por que:** por que la cague pensando que la documentacion no debia ser muy amplia y al parecer ya van por el documento CCTR0920008 y en un par de meses llegaran al limite numerico.

y los ejemplos estos como que no me funcionan muy bien:

```
UPDATE t1 SET NUMER=CONCAT('00000',NUMER) WHERE LENGTH(NUMER)=1;   
UPDATE t1 SET NUMER=CONCAT('0000',NUMER) WHERE LENGTH(NUMER)=2;  
UPDATE t1 SET NUMER=CONCAT('000',NUMER) WHERE LENGTH(NUMER)=3;  

SELECT LPAD(NUMER,6,'0') AS NUMER
FROM ...
```

Comment: tus campos se llaman DocRel y Memo?

Comment: No específicamente, ese es un ejemplo de como se llaman las columnas lo que si es cierto es el contenido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es sencillo utiliza **LPAD** de **MySQL**. Mira en esta página web [LPAD](https://www.taringa.net/posts/ciencia-educacion/16355976/Rellenar-de-ceros-Campos-en-Mysql-despues-de-una-migracion.html)

En tu código sería algo así:

```
UPDATE tutabla set DocRel = LPAD(trim(LEFT(DocRel,11)),18, '0') 
WHERE DocRel like 'CCTR%';
```

Lee la información que te dejé en el link porque posiblemente para ejecutar esta instrucción tengas que configurar antes esto:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

Luego de que actualices lo devuelves al valor por defecto.

**Observación:** Antes de intentar esto por favor realiza un backup por si algo no te sale bien no afectas la data.

Eso es todo. Un Saludo.

Comment: Verifico ok, lo hago en una base de datos de prueba.

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola! ¿Es necesario hacerlo con MySQL? Podrías hacerlo con un script PHP:

```
//Poner datos de BD en un array.-
//...

//Longitud que debe tener en números, sin contar el CCTR.-
$longitud = 11;

//Recorrer y reemplazar.-
$arrayUpdate = [];
foreach($array as $input){

  $arrayUpdate['id'] = $input['id'];

  //Buscamos todas las apariciones de CCTR en la primera celda de la tabla.-
  $arrayUpdate['nombre'] = "";
  $apariciones = explode('CCTR', $input['nombre']);
  foreach(explode('CCTR', $input['nombre']) as $parte){
    //Agregamos '0' de acuerdo con $longitud.-
    $ceros = str_repeat('0', $longitud - strlen(explode(' ', $parte)[0]));
    $arrayUpdate['nombre'] .= 'CCTR'.str_repeat("0", $ceros).$parte;
  }
  $arrayUpdate['nombre'] = $apariciones[0].$arrayUpdate['nombre'];

  //Buscamos todas las apariciones de CCTR en la segunda celda de la tabla.-
  $arrayUpdate['descripcion'] = "";
  $apariciones = explode('CCTR', $input['descripcion']);
  foreach(explode('CCTR', $input['descripcion']) as $parte){
    //Agregamos '0' de acuerdo con $longitud.-
    $ceros = str_repeat('0', $longitud - strlen(explode(' ', $parte)[0]));
    $arrayUpdate['descripcion'] .= 'CCTR'.str_repeat("0", $ceros).$parte;
  }
  $arrayUpdate['descripcion'] = $apariciones[0].$arrayUpdate['descripcion'];

  //Ejecutamos query de Update.-
}
```

No es la forma más elegante, pero si el tiempo te apremia me parece que puede ser una buena opción. No pude probar el código ya que no tengo tu bd, pero debería estar ok.

**Recomendaría respaldar la base de datos antes de realizar esto. También verificar que las llaves foráneas no ser pierdan.**

Espero te sirva,
¡Saludos y éxito!

Comment: Déjame checar ok lo hago en un servidor de pruebas.